# beamer: Create a Custom Frametitle Color for Specific Frames

Tags: beamer

- I have a complex presentation where I use different background graphics.
- **Due to reliability, I need to have a different `frametitle` color for some specific frames (e. g. overview frame).**
- I tried to define a new color and apply it in the `\frametitle` command which didn't work.
- If I use e. g. `\color{blue}` directly then it works.
- What am I missing? I want to use the beamer syntax and framework.
- In addition, where is the `\frametitle` command defined? I wanted to create something like `\usebeamertemplate{frametitle}[Overview]` (as I do for the `background canvas`) but I can't figure it out.
- **I do not want to manually change it because I want to create a theme and therefore I do not want to have to change the content frames manually.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{myOwnColorForTheOverviewFrameTitle}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
% Here I try to apply a different color for a spefific frame
\frametitle{\usebeamercolor{myOwnColorForTheOverviewFrameTitle}Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 1}
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 2}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use formatting commands inside macros such as `\frametitle`, as this is a task for templates. To simply change the colour, you could change the `beamercolor` locally for the frame.

In case you want to do more complex changes, define your own `frametitle` template, examples can be found in the outer themes.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{myOwnColorForTheOverviewFrameTitle}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}


{
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=myOwnColorForTheOverviewFrameTitle}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 1}
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 2}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]